# OOP member variable visibility

Tags: php, oop

I have a few classes that extend "Shop", what's the best way to do this so that parent functions ie: list_items() can be used on child classes?

```
class Shop
{
   public function list_items() {
      foreach($wares as $w)
        echo $w;
   }
   public function buy($item){
   }
}

class Brewery extends Shop
{
   public $wares = array("Wine", "Beer", "Alcohol", "Sake", "Rum");
   public $keepers = array("Jack", "Jill", "Bob", "Sam");
}

function makeShop() //initialize a shop obj
{
  $s = new Brewery();
  $s->list_items(); //$wares is not visible!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

> $this

in foreach in your shop Class.
$this is a keyword for non-static attributes or methods.
with $this you can access all of your class attributes like public $wares.
without $this you can't access your class attributes - this variable is unknown.

```
foreach($this->wares as $w)
```

and call your function makeshop() at the end of your script.:

```
makeshop();
```

So complete:

```
<?php
class Shop
{
   public function list_items() {
      foreach($this->wares as $w)
        echo $w;
   }
   public function buy($item){
   }
}

class Brewery extends Shop
{
   public $wares = array("Wine", "Beer", "Alcohol", "Sake", "Rum");
   public $keepers = array("Jack", "Jill", "Bob", "Sam");
}

function makeShop() //initialize a shop obj
{
  $s = new Brewery();
  $s->list_items(); //$wares is not visible!
}

makeshop();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$wares` indeed is undefined because you should access it using `$this->wares`.

Also always limit visibility of methods and attributes to the maximum. Eg. here you can set it to `protected`.

Next thing is that you should stick with one naming convention. Using `makeShop` and `list_items` in one project is not good idea.

Answer (score 1):

When you extend a class you inherit all its functions. So just refer to them using `$this->list_items()` as you would any other class method.

Answer (score 1):

`$wares` is not visible because it's not coming from anywhere.

Pass it as a function parameter or use it as a class member:

```
public function list_items($wares) {
  foreach($wares as $w)
    echo $w;
}
```

or:

```
class Shop
{
   public $wares = [];
   public function list_items() {
      foreach($this->wares as $w)
        echo $w;
   }
   public function buy($item){
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use all public and protected methods from Shop in the other classes.